# How to create new nested object with checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a nested object of comments in page form

This returns all comments as checkboxes

```
<% for comment in Comment.find(:all)> %>
  <%= check_box_tag "page[comment_ids][]", comment.id, 
    @page.comments.include?(comment) %>
  <%= comment.navn %>
  <br />
<% end %>
```

When I submit the page form. I want it to take those checked checkboxes and create new comments precise as those there is checked and also a association to page.

**Example:

I get a checkbox list of comments in the page form
Comment 1 
Comment 2
I check checkbox 2
When i submit the page form
There is created a new Comment precise as comment2(not the ID), with HABTM association to the page.**

Can someone please tell me how i should create this form?

PS: I am a rails beginner

Comment: First try to get rid of that query `Comment.find(:all)` from view. Second I am not sure what you want obtain. Some help for nested_forms and fields_for http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for

Comment: Adding the "why" for @codevoice's comment: replace `Comment.find(:all)` so that comments are 'scoped' to what is being commented on eg. `@article.comments.all`. This way comments for a different article won't show up for X article. Of course, if you want to show all comments/somethings then use the `find(:all)`, as you are doing.